# N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest' in directory '/et/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extention filename extention

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

in step 1.4 i got this error .help me

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275325/n:-ignoring-file-%27ros-latest%27-in-directory-%27/et/apt/sources.list.d/%27-as-it-has-no-filename-extention-filename-extention/) by [thomn](https://answers.ros.org/users/32542/thomn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Ignoring file 'ros-latest' in directory '/et/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extention filename extension

Perhaps surprisingly, this error seems to be pretty explanatory by itself.

The `ros-latest` file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` is supposed to have a `.list` extension, and it doesn't on your machine.

If with `step 1.4` you are referring to the *Installation* step in the installation manual, then you may have made a mistake in step 1.2 - [Setup your sources](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic/Installation/Ubuntu#Installation.2BAC8-Ubuntu.2BAC8-Sources.Setup_your_sources.list):

> Setup your computer to accept software from packages.ros.org.

> ```
> sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'
> ```

Notice the `.list` extension there.

To resolve this, you could do something like the following:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

then try `sudo apt-get update` again.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0